SQL Server PIVOT includes null values
I have a pivot query and it is returning null values in the output. I've been reading out MS documentation and I don't get why I'm getting multiple rows in the pivoted output
The inner query is as follows:
select r.Casino, wf.WebsiteValue, dsf.Name, wf.DataStoreFieldId
from Review r 
inner join WebsiteField wf on wf.ReviewId = r.Id
inner join DataStoreField dsf on dsf.Id = wf.DataStoreFieldId 
where dsf.Id in (42, 43, 163) 
  and WebsiteValue like '%USD%'
  and Casino = 'Tusk Casino'

and returns the following:
Casino        WebsiteValue     Name                           DataStoreFieldId
------------ ----------------- ------------------------------ ----------------
Tusk Casino   EUR/USD 16,000   Withdrawal per Month           42
Tusk Casino   EUR/USD 4,000    Withdrawal per Week            43
Tusk Casino   EUR/USD 1,000    Withdrawal Per Transaction     163

The pivot query is:
select 
    Casino as 'Casino', 
    [42] as 'Withdrawal per Week', 
    [43] as 'Withdrawal per Month', 
    [163] as 'Withdrawal Per Transaction' 
from
    (select 
         r.Casino, wf.WebsiteValue, dsf.Name as FieldName, wf.DataStoreFieldId
     from 
         Review r 
     inner join 
         WebsiteField wf on wf.ReviewId = r.Id
     inner join 
         DataStoreField dsf on dsf.Id = wf.DataStoreFieldId 
     where 
         dsf.Id in (42, 43, 163) 
         and Casino = 'Tusk Casino' 
         and WebsiteValue like '%USD%') as source
pivot
    (MAX(WebsiteValue)  
     FOR DataStoreFieldId IN ([42], [43], [163])  
    ) AS PivotTable
where 
    Casino = 'Tusk Casino' 
order by 
    Casino

And this returns the following output:
Casino       Withdrawal per Week  Withdrawal per Month  Withdrawal Per Transaction
------------ -------------------- --------------------- --------------------------
Tusk Casino  EUR/USD 16,000       NULL                  NULL
Tusk Casino  NULL                 NULL                  EUR/USD 1,000
Tusk Casino  NULL                 EUR/USD 4,000         NULL

How do I get rid of the NULLs and return the pivoted output as one row?

Honestly, forget PIVOT exists; use conditional aggregation. I suspect I know the answer, but I can't double check without sample data.

Out of curiosity what made you decide to quote 42 using [] and the alias using '' in eg the line [42] as 'Withdrawal per Week'? You should always use [] not ''. Anyway, remove dsf.Name as FieldName from the subquery and it will work.

Thanks @Charlieface you were spot on. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Why is it better to use [] for aliases instead of '' ?

They have some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced, @AdamHey . For example ORDER BY 'Withdrawal per Week' achieves literally nothing, and SELECT 'Withdrawal per Week' FROM (SELECT 123 AS 'Withdrawal per Week') SQ returns 'Withdrawal per Week' not 123. NOt to mention some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you must delimit identify them use T-SQL's identifier, brackets ([]), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (").

The problem is your inner SELECT, you are SELECTing dsf.Name and as that column is neither in your aggregate function, or in your FOR in the PIVOT it is therefore (effectively) in your GROUP BY, and therefore you get one row per value of FieldName. If you remove that column from the inner SELECT, then it would work as you want.
Of course, as I state in the comments, forget PIVOT exists; it's a restrictive operator and I find many struggle with it or use it incorrectly. Instead use far simpler, but also far less restrictive, conditional aggregation:
SELECT Casino,
       MAX(CASE FieldName WHEN 'Withdrawal per Week' THEN WebsiteValue END) AS [Withdrawal per Week], --Don't use single quotes for aliases
       MAX(CASE FieldName WHEN 'Withdrawal per Month' THEN WebsiteValue END) AS [Withdrawal per Month], --Don't use single quotes for aliases
       MAX(CASE FieldName WHEN 'Withdrawal per Transaction' THEN WebsiteValue END) AS [Withdrawal per Transaction] --Don't use single quotes for aliases
--VALUES for sample data
FROM (VALUES('Tusk Casino','asdakhjd','Withdrawal per Week',42),
            ('Tusk Casino','ksdbjfgl','Withdrawal per Month',43),
            ('Tusk Casino','sdfk;ghsd;f','Withdrawal Per Transaction',163))V(Casino,WebsiteValue,FieldName,DataStoreFieldId)
GROUP BY Casino;


For reference the query you have, and is working incorrectly, would effectively be this, which might help you better understand what is occurring:
SELECT Casino,
       MAX(CASE DataStoreFieldId WHEN 42 THEN WebsiteValue END) AS [Withdrawal per Week], --Don't use single quotes for aliases
       MAX(CASE DataStoreFieldId WHEN 43 THEN WebsiteValue END) AS [Withdrawal per Month], --Don't use single quotes for aliases
       MAX(CASE DataStoreFieldId WHEN 163 THEN WebsiteValue END) AS [Withdrawal per Transaction] --Don't use single quotes for aliases
FROM (VALUES('Tusk Casino','asdakhjd','Withdrawal per Week',42),
            ('Tusk Casino','ksdbjfgl','Withdrawal per Month',43),
            ('Tusk Casino','sdfk;ghsd;f','Withdrawal Per Transaction',163))V(Casino,WebsiteValue,FieldName,DataStoreFieldId)
GROUP BY Casino,
         FieldName;

